# Split calculation of an algorithm on Google App Engine application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scalability

I'm a new user of Google App Engine and use it for the purpose of a student project.

I'm trying to do an application where I have to apply a specific algorithm to match users by their localisation on the globe.
But I don't really see how I am supposed, practically, to split the calculation depending of the number of users. I was thinking about mapReduce, but it seems that it doesn't really fit with my algorithm and I don't see any other way.

For instance, if I want to match one user (on a request) with many others (here 20 000), it takes five secondes on my local server. Would like to make it scalable using GAE.
(I'm using Python)

Any clue about how I could manage it ?

Comment: Could you clarify what "match users by their localisation" means? Are you trying to find all users in the same "area"? the nearest (one or multiple)?

Comment: I'm matching user (with longitude, latitude, and a "radius of vision") with others, using great circle algorithm. At the end I need to get a list of users which are visibles by the requesting user.

Comment: you'll likely find it'll run much much slower then you are doing it locally. Check the specs of the instances!

Comment: unless you are constrained to a particular implementation, you don't need to re-invent the wheel. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/geopointclass

Comment: What @PaulCollingwood says is true, using the Search API, a GeoPoint field and queries (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/query_strings#Python_Queries_on_geopoint_fields) seems the way to go

Comment: It seems so, but I don't really see how I'm supposed to use the Search API because my users are stored using NDB in my Datastore. I'm still trying to find a way through.
(Thanks for the hints about geoPoint !)

Comment: run a conversion job to create the required records for existing users, then add them as you add new users from then on. Reference the search record from the user record etc. How else? :P

Comment: Hm... No other way? :D I'm worried about the processing time on each request. It will affect it, no? I'll try and continue to do research about other ways using only NDB.

Comment: Alternately a geohash scheme may work for you - https://code.google.com/p/geomodel/